# How to make installation of etherdelta smart contract

Tags: etherdelta

this is the following smart contract
https://github.com/gochainwallet/forkdelta.github.io/tree/master/smart_contract

The question is how to build and get the bytecode?
The other thing using .sol and remix i could build my own smart contract to receive the fees of coins?

Comment: I think the project with the contract is in a separate repository
https://github.com/gochainwallet/smart_contract-1, it has instruction how to start in the readme (I didn't verify that they work).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [truffle](https://truffleframework.com/), **the** framework for deploying smart contracts on ethereum. There is a really good step-by-step documentation to find [here](https://truffleframework.com/docs).

Comment: Hello i installed truffle but for this project i have some doubts. i just create an example like this `truffle unbox metacoin`, but after i just must to edit the contracts and then? how to build the contracts?

Comment: i tried to compile using solcjs than is more easier but getting some errors too. token.sol:1:1: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/inter
ace/library definition.